# Restore unique permissions in 2010

Tags: 2010, permissions

A customer accidently clicked on Inherit Permissions on a Team Site in 2010. Is it possible to revert this action and get back all the unique permissions?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible OOTB. There is a workaround for it. If you have either Site collection backups or Content Database Backup then you can restore it from before the Inheritance enabled.

Or if you have any security related reports then apply the setting manually.